# SSRS Select last record from group of rows using parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I ve been searching in SO but found nothing that solved that problem

I m using SSRS native mode and i want to create a report with a filter based on the parameter @idRiskType.

Consider the following table : (risktrail)

[image]

I have created a stored procedure to find the last risk type for all customers and it works fine . Here it is :

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[byRisk] @riskType int
 as
 select c.idCustomer, rsTrail.idRiskType
 from customer as c
  cross apply 
      (select top 1 idRiskType
       from risktrail 
       where risktrail.idCustomer = c.idCustomer
       order by idTrail desc) as rsTrail
```

This stored procedure outpouts the following :

[image]

- Problem : The problem is that i don't know how to apply the parameter @riskType to filter only the LAST risks that match the parameter .
  i.e If i apply the parameter in the where clause using an AND operator the query will return any row of the table that matches the parameter but i want it only to return rows that indicate the LAST valid idRiskType for each customer.

Comment: Have you tried an extra WHERE outside of the subquery?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.  Given your sample data, what is your desired output?

Comment: Have you tried just adding "WHERE rsTrail.idRiskType = @idRiskType" to the end?

Comment: Can you provide the expected result please? Didn't you already find "LAST valid idRiskType for each customer" in your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[byRisk] @riskType int
 as
 select c.idCustomer, rsTrail.idRiskType
 from customer as c
  cross apply 
  (select top 1 idRiskType
   from risktrail 
   where risktrail.idCustomer = c.idCustomer
   order by idTrail desc) as rsTrail  
  where rsTrail.idRiskType = @idRiskType
```